# type mismatch between inferred value and length of vector

Tags: idris

Trying to solve the exercise about matrix multiplication in [*Type driven development with Idris*](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) has led me into an annoying problem.

So far I've ended up defining a set of helper functions like this:

```
morexs : (n : Nat) -> Vect m a -> Vect n (Vect m a)
morexs n xs = replicate n xs

mult_cols : Num a => Vect m (Vect n a) -> Vect m (Vect n a) -> Vect m (Vect n a)
mult_cols xs ys = zipWith (zipWith (*)) xs ys

mult_mat_helper : Num a => Vect m a -> Vect n (Vect m a) -> Vect n a
mult_mat_helper xs ys =
    let len = the Nat (length ys) in
    map sum (mult_cols (morexs len xs) ys)
```

However, the typechecker complaints that there is a "Type mismatch between the inferred value and given value" in `replicate (length ys) xs`:

```
When checking right hand side of mult_mat_helper with expected type
        Vect n a

When checking argument n to function Main.morexs:
        Type mismatch between
                n (Inferred value)
        and
                len (Given value)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        n
                and
                        length ys
```

**why does this mismatch occur?** *`ys` is length `n` and I replicate `n` times, so I don't see the problem :/*

*Originally I defined my function like this:*

```
mult_mat_helper : Num a => Vect m a -> Vect n (Vect m a) -> Vect n a
mult_mat_helper xs ys =
    let
        xs2 = replicate (length ys) xs
        zs = zipWith (zipWith (*)) xs2 ys
    in
    map sum zs
```

*but got following error:*

```
When checking right hand side of mult_mat_helper with expected type
        Vect n a

When checking argument m to function Prelude.Functor.map:
        a is not a numeric type
```

*I tried running through all the steps with some test data in the repl and everything worked fine... The code, however, refuses to go through the type checker*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`length` has the type of

```
Data.Vect.length : Vect n a -> Nat
```

It returns some `Nat`. The type checker does not know that the `Nat` is actually `n` - so it cannot unify between both values. Actually, you don't even need `length`. The documentation says

> Note: this is only useful if you don't already statically know the
>   length and you want to avoid matching the implicit argument for
>   erasure reasons.

So instead of `length` we can match on the implicit argument.

```
mult_mat_helper : Num a => Vect m a -> Vect n (Vect m a) -> Vect n a
mult_mat_helper {n} xs ys = map sum (mult_cols (morexs n xs) ys)
```